# Inserting html as plain text into textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a list and add its structure to the textarea as plain text. The following works but it is only adding the first input:

**HTML**

```
<div id="mindmap">
  <ul>
    <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-default ul-appending">+ Node</button>      </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="mindMapData">
  <textarea col="10" rows="10"></textarea>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('body').on('click', 'button.ul-appending', function() {
    $(this).parent().append(
    $('<ul class="main_ul">').addClass('newul sortable').append(
    $('<li><input placeholder="Link title" class="nome_link form-control" type="text"><input placeholder="Link" class="form-control link_url" type="text"></li>')
    )
    );
});

$('body').on('click', 'button.removeThis', function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().remove();
});

function ul(indent) {
    indent = indent || 4;
  var node = $(this);
    return node.removeAttr('class').children().map(function() {
    var self = $(this);
    var value = self.find('> input').val();
    var sub_ul = self.find('> ul');
    var ul_spaces = new Array(indent+4).join(' ');
    var li_spaces = new Array(indent).join(' ');
    if (sub_ul.length && ul) {
        return li_spaces + '<li>' + value + '\n' + ul_spaces +
          '<ul class="sortable">\n' + ul.call(sub_ul, indent+8) + '\n' + ul_spaces + '<ul>\n' +
          li_spaces + '</li>';
    } else {
        return li_spaces + '<li><a href="'+ $(".link_url").text() + '">' + value + '</a></li>';
    }
  }).get().join('\n');
}

function updateTree() {
   $("#mindMapData textarea").text('<ul class="sortable">\n' + $("#mindMap").clone().find('.main_ul').map(ul).get().join('\n') + '\n</ul>');
 }

$("#mindMap").on("DOMSubtreeModified", updateTree);
$("#mindMap").on('keyup', 'input', updateTree);
```

The output would have to be like

```
<li><a href="www.exampleA.com">My example A</a></li>
<li><a href="www.exampleB.com">My example B</a></li>
<li><a href="www.exampleC.com">My example C</a></li>
<li><a href="www.exampleD.com">My example D</a></li>
```

I have set up [a JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/44yb96Lb/244/) where you can see that it does add one input and even if you add nodes only the first inputs gets placed

Comment: so it is adding <li></li> but you want like <li> <input /> </li> in the fiddle?

Comment: @JohnVandivier nope I would like to have thee whole <li><a href="www.exampleA.com">My example A</a></li> for each node

Comment: the problem was not the thing that you said, the only problem is that you didn't define any `a` tag in your code

Comment: @MajidNayyeri oh sorry, forgot to include it. I had stripped the code with other bits i had and I forgot, updating now, hang on

Comment: @MajidNayyeri I have updated the jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/44yb96Lb/244/

Comment: @JohnVandivier updated  http://jsfiddle.net/44yb96Lb/244/

Comment: So now nodes are fine but `a` tags can't get the link . right ?
No difference between first and last node ...

Comment: @MajidNayyeri yes basically I cannot get the link into the <a tag and it doesn't update when I am typing on key up

Answer (score 0):

This is how I resolved it, basically I had to set 2 different vars for the 2 input fields

```
$('body').on('click', 'button.ul-appending', function() {
    $(this).parent().append(
    $('<ul class="main_ul">').addClass('newul sortable').append(
    $('<li><input placeholder="Link title" class="nome_link form-control" type="text"><input placeholder="Link" class="form-control link_url" type="text"></li>')
    )
    );
});

function ul(indent) {
    indent = indent || 4;
  var node = $(this);
    return node.removeAttr('class').children().map(function() {
    var self = $(this);
    var value = self.find('> .nome_link').val();
    var valueB = self.find('> .link_url').val();
    var sub_ul = self.find('> ul');
    var ul_spaces = new Array(indent+4).join(' ');
    var li_spaces = new Array(indent).join(' ');
    if (sub_ul.length && ul) {
        return li_spaces + '<li>' + value + '\n' + ul_spaces +
          '<ul class="sortable">\n' + ul.call(sub_ul, indent+8) + '\n' + ul_spaces + '<ul>\n' +
          li_spaces + '</li>';
    } else {
        return li_spaces + '<li><a href="'+valueB+'">' + value + '</a></li>';
    }
  }).get().join('\n');
}

function updateTree() {
   $("#mindMapData textarea").text('<ul>\n' + $("#mindMap").clone().find('.main_ul').map(ul).get().join('\n') + '\n</ul>');
}

$("#mindMap").on("DOMSubtreeModified", updateTree);
$("#mindMap").on('keyup', 'input', updateTree);
```